# Monorails. Although I use Rescue attributes, 500 "Error processing action" is still thrown

Tags: castle-monorail

In my monorails project. I use attribute Rescue

```
[Rescue("generalerror", typeof(System.Exception))]
```

but the error 500 "Error processing action" still is thrown. How can I hide it?

Comment: What version of IIS are you running on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hm, do you have a view called "generalerror.vm" or equivalent? (.vm is NVelocity suffix).

If you don't specify ExceptionType, then it will catch it for all exceptions as well, so you don't need to specify it explicitly.

If your rescue is on a separate controller, then you need this syntax:

```
[Rescue( typeof( RescueController ), "Index" )]
```

Where "Index" is the action on RescueController that would be invoked upon failure.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure have view called "generalerror" place it in Views/Rescues